# How to invite a player to a GKTurnBasedMatch programatically in iOS 8

Tags: ios, game-center

I see the **playersToInvite** property of a GKMatchRequest class has been deprecated as of iOS 8*.  How does one now create a match request programmatically so as to play against a friend on game centre?

I haven't been able to find any info on the interwebs on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use the recipients property:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKMatchRequest/recipients